# `which deactivate` command in a `Python` virtual enviroment prints out the whole function instead of a location

Tags: python, unix, command, virtual, environment

I simply create a `Ptyhon` virtual environment:

```bash
python -m venv venv
```

and activate it:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then I run:

```bash
which deactive
```

and suppose to get a location, but I get:

```
deactivate () {
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}" ]
    then
        PATH="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}" ]
    then
        PYTHONHOME="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi
    if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]
    then
        hash -r 2> /dev/null
    fi
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}" ]
    then
        PS1="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi
    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    unset VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT
    if [ ! "${1:-}" = "nondestructive" ]
    then
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}
```

What happens behind the scenes?

Can anyone explain it?

Thanks a lot!

Based on my limited previous experience, `which` command always gives a location!

Comment: Try to change the `which deactive` to `where deactive`

Comment: Thank you for the comment! It's interesting! Inside the virtual environment, `where deactivate` prints out the function, the same as `which deactivate` did, but is followed by a location.